# Android getSupportedPreviewSizes() on Camera returns only 3 sizes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-camera

I'm using the Android Camera API to build a camera app and I need to set the preview size of the camera. I've read that I'm supposed to call `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` on my camera object's Parameter object to obtain a list of every supported size. The problem is that this list contains three sizes: 640x480, 352x288 and 320x240.

I'm using Android Studio and the built in emulator. I've tried emulating Nexus 5, 6 and 10 and they all give me those three sizes. So I suspect it's a restriction from the emulator. If so, is there anyway to get around it? Or is this occuring because of something else?

Comment: "is there anyway to get around it?" -- to get around *what*? Cameras on hardware can return any number of preview sizes, and it's eminently possible that there will be hardware that happens to also return these three preview sizes. Please explain, in detail, what problem you are having with these three preview sizes.

Comment: @CommonsWare The problem is that the biggest size 640x480 takes up about 1/4 or 1/3 of the display, when I want it to cover the entire screen.

Comment: you may stretch it to fit display size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preview size will rarely, if ever, exactly match the size of the surface on which you are rendering the previews. `SurfaceView` and `TextureView` will scale the previews to fill the available space of those views.

Your job, therefore, is to size the surface as big as you want to be, while maintaining the aspect ratio of the previews, so the scaling does not stretch or squash the image. [Grafika's `AspectFrameLayout`](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/AspectFrameLayout.java), or possibly [my `AspectLockedFrameLayout`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts#usage-aspectlockedframelayout), are ways of achieving that, as would subclassing `SurfaceView` or `TextureView` and overriding `onMeasure()`.

Comment: I see, so then the preview sizes is kinda a of list of different applied ratios? (Although both 640x480 and 320x240 have the same ratio, which is weird?). I was under the influence that the SurfaceView/TextureView needed to be one of the available preview sizes.

Comment: @lawls: "then the preview sizes is kinda a of list of different applied ratios?" -- well, no, they are resolutions. "Although both 640x480 and 320x240 have the same ratio, which is weird?" -- for your app, perhaps those are redundant. For other apps, having a lower resolution preview may be advantageous (e.g., faster preview image processing).

Comment: Well explained. Thank you!